# High Sierra issue with Axure

Tags: macos, high-sierra

**Using High Sierra with Axure 8.0.**

When i go to "Applications" folder in Finder and press to open Axure.app twice, thrice.... It launches 2, 3, 4 and more instances of Axure.app, i think it's wrong behavior..

I expect following behavior: 
if you click to open already running app it should focus on this running app instead of launching another instance of this running app..

Comment: Okay. But wouldn’t it be better to tell Axure?

Comment: Already did, bro

Comment: Cool story, bro

Comment: @JohnKeates, btw, do you experience the same behavior?

Comment: Well, no. I did see the same thing happening with other apps that were written in C# and packaged for Mac later on, but that was mostly with older apps. Most of the time when the app opens many versions of itself it's crashing or programmed the wrong way.

Comment: So it's Axure for sure should update their program...